# Appending elements specified in a string with quotes to a bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I am trying to append an item to an array that is stored in a variable, however it's not acting entirely how I'd expect it to.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
array=()

item_to_add="1 '2 3'"

array+=(${item_to_add})

for item in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "item: ${item}"
done
```

I'd expect this to output the following:

```
item: 1
item: '2 3'
```

However I get the following output instead:

```
item: 1
item: '2
item: 3'
```

Is there any way to make it act like this code without using something like `eval`?

```
array=()

array+=(1 '2 3')

for item in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "item: ${item}"
done
```

And the output from it:

```
item: 1
item: '2 3'
```

Comment: How do you expect to parse quotes without going back to a parsing stage that, err, parses quotes?

Comment: ...and what's the real use case here? If you're trying to read a parameter list from a file, for instance, there's a better way to do it. (Short form: Put contents in the file in NUL-delimited form, which can be directly represented as a shell array without any kind of parsing needed).

Comment: Why don't you just make `item_to_add` an array in the first place?

Comment: There's no way to do it without `eval`. Quotes are not processed when expanding variables.

Comment: I wouldn't *quite* say "no way". You can use an external program that knows how to parse quotes -- `xargs`, for instance. Actually, let me write up an answer that does that...

Comment: Are you constrained that your input is a quote delimited string and therefore can't use what @Barmar suggested? Tell us your restrictions and we'll suggest a workaround.

Comment: Yes @alvits, my input is a string containing quotes which is why I'm trying to do it the way I am.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 goes into some very related territory re: the reasoning behind this bug, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xargs` parses quotes in its input. This is usually a (specification-level) bug rather than a feature (it makes filenames with literal quotations nearly impossible to work with without non-POSIX extensions such as `-d` or `-0` overriding the behavior), but in present circumstances it comes in quite handy:

```
array=()

item_to_add="1 '2 3'"

while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do # read NUL-delimited stream
  array+=( "$item" )              # and add each piece to an array
done < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$item_to_add") # transform string to NUL-delimited stream

printf 'item: %s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

...emits...

```
item: 1
item: 2 3
```

Comment: This can be simplified. See my answer.

Comment: I disagree -- strongly -- with "simplifications" that trade against correctness.