# Bash splitting line with quotes into parameters

Tags: linux, bash

hope this question did not occur before. At least I did not find an answer. Maybe didn't look well :(

Let's assume I got this piece of text:

```
hello "hello" "hello world"
```

Please tell me why these two scripts have different output?:

1) the text is saved in file

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
    do
        set $line
        echo $1
        echo $2
        echo $3
    done < "file"
```

The output is:

```
hello
"hello"
"hello
```

2) text hardcoded in script

```
#!/bin/bash
set hello "hello" "hello world"
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

Here's the output:

```
hello
hello
hello world
```

I would like to get the second behavior while reading line from different file. Please, stackers, help :(

Comment: This is closely related to BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: BTW, `echo $1`; `echo $2`; `echo $3` is buggy -- look at what happens if you have `"*"` in your input. Always, *always*, **always** quote your expansions: `echo "$1"`, `echo "$2"`, `echo "$3"`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779095/appending-elements-specified-in-a-string-with-quotes-to-a-bash-array/38780049

Comment: Also related (perhaps enough so to be a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067249/bash-reading-quoted-escaped-arguments-correctly-from-a-string

Comment: BTW -- if you don't use `IFS=` on your `read`s, leading and trailing whitespace gets split, and if you don't use `-r`, then literal backslashes are parsed as directives to `read`. It's a good habit to use both by default unless you explicitly *want* the behaviors they suppress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a rough version of what you want using `xargs`, which parses quotes, backslashes, &c. in a roughly shell-equivalent manner:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    xargs printf '%s\n' <<<"$line"
done <file
```

If you want to read those contents into positional arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do

    set --                                   # clear the argument list
    while IFS= read -r -d '' element; do     # read a NUL-delimited element
      set -- "$@" "$element"                 # append to the argument list
    done < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <<<"$line") # write NUL-delimited elements

    echo "$1"          # add quotes to make your code less buggy
    echo "$2"
    echo "$3"

done <file
```

Comment: That's the solution i've been looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

This is a shell command:

```
set hello "hello" "hello world"
```

Because it is a shell command, the shell performs *quote removal* as the last step before executing the command.

Contrast that with the text in a file:

```
$ cat file
hello "hello" "hello world"
```

When the shell reads this file, it treats the quotes as just another character.  The quotes in this file never appear directly on a command line and they are, consequently, not subject to *quote removal*.

### Documentation

From the section in `man bash` discussing expansions:

> **Quote Removal**
>
> After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters \, ', and " that did not result from  one  of  the  above 
>   expansions  are removed.

### How word splitting and quote removal interact

Bash does *word splitting* before it does quote removal.  That is important, for example, for this command:

```
set hello "hello" "hello world"
```

When the shell does its word splitting, it finds three arguments to the `set` command.  It is only as the last step before executing `set` that the shell does quote removal.  Since no further word splitting is done, the number of arguments to `set` remains as three.

Let's contrast the above with the result of reading a line from the file:

```
$ cat file
hello "hello" "hello world"
$ read line <file
$ echo "$line"
hello "hello" "hello world"
```

As discussed above, the shell does no quote removal on the contents of `line`.  Now, let's use `$line` as the argument to `set`:

```
$ set $line
$ echo $#
4
```

Four arguments are found.  Those arguments are:

```
$ echo 1=$1 2=$2 3=$3 4=$4
1=hello 2="hello" 3="hello 4=world"
```

As you can see, the quotes in the file are treated as just plain ordinary characters, the same as, say, `h` or `e`.  Consequently, `"hello world"` from the file is expanded as two words, each having one quote character.

Comment: Quite so.  This would be a more complete answer, however, if it also addressed how quoting and variable interpolation interact with word splitting, which is also in play here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger OK.  I added a section on the interaction of word splitting and quote removal.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a lot while studying materials you provided :) And thanks a lot for the tip with quotes while "echo'ing" variables!